# Electrum Gap Limit from CLI

Tags: development, electrum, script, python, cli

Is there any way to change wallet gap limit in Electrum from command line? If yes, how? If not, could it be bypassed using some kind of external script? I really need to avoid GUI. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22606/more-receive-addresses-with-electrum) no longer work?

Comment: @RaghavSood console there means the python console in the QT gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to edit the json code in the wallet file and add the gap limit into it. You can do that using the command line tool jq:

`jq ". + {gap_limit:100}" wallet_file`

Comment: Is necessary to run the daemon to refresh addresses?

Comment: @MichalVales yes you'll likely have to restart electrum to get it to generate the new addresses and sync.